# Is mixed measures ANOVA the correct test for my data?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model

I'm fairly new to statistics and I'm still trying to figure out the best way to analyse the data I have. The experiment has 2 groups of participants who perform 2 repetitions of a task that consists of 5 stages. All participants completed both repetitions for all stages, but one group had 8 participants while the other group only had 6. I have a about 100 dependent variables that I wish to examine, so my data looks a bit like this:

```
ID   Group    Repetition    Stage   DV1    DV2     ...
1    A        1             1       212.9  179.9   ...
1    A        2             1       144.8  134.7   ...
2    B        1             1       146.3  156.8   ...
2    B        2             1       128.6  178.2   ...
```

Group is a between-subjects factor while Repetition and Stage are within-subjects factors. I would like to determine whether Group and Repetition have a significant effect on each dependent variable within each stage (I am not interested in the effect of stage itself). I'm doing the analysis in R so I have the following code:

```
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))
mydata            = read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE)
mydata$Group      = factor(mydata$Group)
mydata$Repetition = factor(mydata$Repetition)
mydata$Stage      = factor(mydata$Stage)
# for each stage
mydata = mydata[mydata$Stage==1,]
for (i in 5:(ncol(mydata))) 
{
   fit = aov(formula=as.formula(paste(names(mydata)[i], 
                                "~ Group * Repetition + Error(ID/Repetition)")), 
             data=mydata)
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is mixed measures ANOVA a valid test for this data? What's the correct way to test whether my data fits the assumptions of ANOVA in R? If this is not a reliable test, what's a possible alternative?
2. Have I defined the mixed measures ANOVA in R correctly? The various tutorials I've read define it in different ways so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I would recommend using `nlme`'s `lme` or `lme4`'s `lmer` function. They are better documented and with cleaner syntax. In the long run their flexibility will definitely prove beneficial. I think what you are doing appears sensible. Just be weary of *multiple testing* and *data dredging* issues.